# react native redux payload always returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have created an app using react native typescript and redux. I have successfully configured the store and everything. But the problem is when I tried to login, I dispatch payload to authReducer and it returns undefined.

`store.tsx`

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import rootReducer from "../_redux/reducers/index";

const persistConfig = {
    key: "root",
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    whitelist: ["authReducer"],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(createLogger()));
let persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

`authReducer.tsx`

```
export const initState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {},
    token: "No Token",
};

const rootReducer = (state = initState, action: any) => {
    if (action.type === "LOG_IN") {
        const { isAuthenticated, user, token } = action.payload;
        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated,
            user,
            token,
        };
    }

    if (action.type === "LOG_OUT") {
        const { isAuthenticated, user, token } = action.payload;
        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated,
            user,
            token,
        };
    }

    if (action.type === "UPDATE_PROFILE") {
        return {
            ...state,
            user: {
                ...state.user,
                name: action.name,
                email: action.email,
                phone: action.phone,
            },
        };
    }

    return state;
};

export default rootReducer;
```

`Login.tsx`

```
    axios
        .post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        })
        .then((response) => {
            setLoading(false);

            if (response.data.success) {
                // response.data.user_data = {user_id: 1, user_name: "Jithin Varghese", user_email: "jithin@gmail.com", user_phone: "1234567890"}
                // response.data.token = 1
                logIn(true, response.data.user_data, response.data.token);
                navigation.navigate("Home");
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            setLoading(false);
        });
    };

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
    logIn: ({ isAuthenticated, user, token }: any) => {
        dispatch({
            type: "LOG_IN",
            payload: {
                isAuthenticated,
                user,
                token,
            },
        });
    },
});

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated,
    user: state.authReducer.user,
    token: state.authReducer.token,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

The `isAuthenticated, user, token` is always undefined after dispatch. You can check the below screenshot for more details.

`Initial load`

[image]

`After login axios call dispatch (logIn(true, response.data.user_data, response.data.token))`

[image]

I have tried a lot to find a solution and I couldn't find any. What is the problem. I cannot figure this out.

I think `prev state` is causing the problem. It is empty initially.

Comment: did you try to console log payload in the reducer?, so you can check that your dispatcher works correctly

Comment: @ThatGuyKev Showing as `{isAuthenticated: undefined, user: undefined, token: undefined}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're passing 3 args to "logIn" instead of 1 arg as an object
instead of calling it like:  `logIn(true, response.data.user_data, response.data.token);`
it should be like

```
 logIn({isAuthenticated:true, user:response.data.user_data, token:response.data.token});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Another solution is adding types to each parameter `logIn: (isAuthenticated: any, user: any, token: any) => {`

Comment: yup that also should fix the problem as your "logIn" can accept 3 args with that. anyhow, good luck with the rest

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing data correctly in Action. You need to pass one argument and you are passing three arguments.

You need to pass data like this

```
logIn(isAuthenticated:true , user: response.data.user_data, token: response.data.token)
```